# Update all rows of a single column from one table to the same table in another database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Ok, so I have a database in my testing environment called 'Food'. In this database, there is a table called 'recipe', with a column called 'source'.

This same database exists in my local environment. However, I just received an updated database (in my local environment) where all the column values (for 'source') have changed.

Is there any way I can migrate the 'source' column from my local to my test environment, without changing the values for any other column? There are 1186 rows in the 'Food' database 'recipe' table in my test environment that need to be updated ONLY with the 'source' column.

Answer (score 0):

You need some way to uniquely identify your Recipes. If both tables have a surrogate key that remained constant, use that. Otherwise figure out some way to match up the new data with your test data: you might already have a unique index in mind or you might need to decide on a combination of fields that uniquely identify your Recipes.

On a side note, why can't you just overwrite all the columns? It is just test data, right?

Comment: They are uniquely identified by a node id column, which acts as the primary key. I will try what Stefan said above and create an intermediate table locally, then mysqldump and import it into the test server table.

I cannot overwrite all columns, because people have been entering in more up to date recipe information in the test server 'Food' database.

Answer (score 0):

If only a column has changed and you have IDs (or keys) on your rows, you could follow these steps:

- create an intermediate table locally
- insert keys and new source values there (either those which have changed or all)
- use `mysqldump` to selectively export the table from the local database
- copy the dumped table to the remote database server
- import it there
- join it with the production table in an update statement to replace the values
- drop the intermediate table on the server

Comment: This table has a node id column (which exists in the table on both servers), which acts as a primary key, so this should work. Thank you!